# Hosting C# Discord bot on a Debian 8 VPS

Tags: c#, mono, discord, discord.net, debian-jessie

I'm trying to get my discord C# bot to host on my Debian 8 VPS. I've not worked with Linux a lot before and I tried, but can't seem to find how to run my bot/code on my VPS.

If it's possible can a step-by-step be provided? I already installed Mono (because I've read that I need that).

PS: Not a big coder. Using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker, editing my question seems a little rude to me...

Comment: Make your bot in .NET Core and then install [dotnet](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxredhat) on the Linux machine. I've done this and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know specifically which bot you want to run? Nadeko is a C# bot, but it uses dotnet core/standard rather than Mono. Instructions for getting it up and running can be found here: http://nadekobot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/Linux%20Guide/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a pre-existing bot, make sure it uses dotnet core or mono for cross compatability (as Markus said) - If you're making it yourself, install dotnet core and make your bot using that instead of a standard dotnet version.

Dotnet Core: https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows